# With Node.js why might dotenv trigger an error if it is not included in additional files besides app.js?

Tags: node.js, dotenv

**Environment:** Node.js, dotenv

`require('dotenv').config()` is typically only required in the main file such as app.js.  With that one call `process.env` can be referenced in every file in the app.  This answer agrees with that, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58697426/12582054

However I just ran across an instance where I get an error if I don't include `require('dotenv').config()` in an additional file and I'm not sure why.

**Simplified Example:**

app.js

```
const path = require('path');

// Custom path to .env file.
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/models/.env')});

const middlewareFile = require('./controllers/middleware-file');
```

middleware-file.js

```
const USPS = require('usps-webtools-promise').default;

const usps = new USPS({
    userId: process.env.USPS_USER_ID,
    properCase: Boolean
});
```

*usps-webtools-promise appears to be the module triggering the error.*

If I don't include the dotenv reference at the top of middleware-file.js the USPS module throws an error.  It points exactly at the first letter of the value `process.env.USPS_USER_ID`.

> throw new error_1.default("Must pass USPS userId");
>
> USPSError [USPS Webtools Error]: Must pass USPS userId
>
> at Object. (c:\website\controllers\middleware-file.js:35:14)

I can solve the error by adding dotenv to the top of the file.

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '../models/.env')});
```

Comment: Can you try `const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/models/.env')}); console.log({dotenv});` in app.js?

Comment: @pzaenger console came back, `ReferenceError: dotenv is not defined`

Comment: That's not so good. Please check your package.json. Did you add `dotenv` to your dependencies?

Comment: `"dotenv": "^8.2.0"`, it works fine throughout the app which is several thousand lines.  It is called a hundred times and except for this one instance works as expected.

Comment: Do you call `require('dotenv').config(...)` more than once? Normally you would call it just once: [_As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv._](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: That was it!  I bumped it up to the top of app.js and it worked.  Thanks so much!  Maybe make an official answer so I can check it.

Comment: Sounds good. Glad, I could help you :)

Comment: Related question about dotenv: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817956/470749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to call `require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '../models/.env')});` [as early as possible in your application](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Further you can log the results or check for errors with:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '/models/.env')});

if (dotenv.error) {
  // Something went wrong
  console.error(dotenv.error);
} else {
  // Log parsed values
  console.log(dotenv.parsed);
}
```