ReferenceError: dotenv is not defined in Node.js with PM2
I'm encountering a ReferenceError: dotenv is not defined issue in my Node.js backend application managed by PM2. Here’s the breakdown:
Environment Details:
Node.js version: 18.20.5
PM2 version: 5.x
Backend framework: Express.js
Problem Description:
When I try to run my application with PM2, I see the following error in the logs:
ReferenceError: dotenv is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/DevTrust/backend/server.js:20:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)

What I've Tried So Far:

Installed dotenv using: npm install dotenv --force
Verified it’s in node_modules using npm list dotenv
Ensured the top of server.js has:
javascript
require('dotenv').config();
Verified .env exists in the backend folder and contains required variables:
makefile


OPENAI_API_KEY=your_actual_api_key
Restarted PM2 with:
bash

pm2 restart backend
pm2 save

Tried running the server directly using node server.js (it works fine).
Logs from PM2:
When running pm2 logs backend --lines 50, I see repeated ReferenceError: dotenv is not defined.
Expected Behavior:
The backend server should load environment variables from the .env file without any errors when started with PM2.
Actual Behavior:
It keeps failing with ReferenceError: dotenv is not defined.
How can I ensure that dotenv is properly loaded and recognized by PM2 when running the backend server?
Any insights or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Please, provide a way to reproduce. The error means that "dotenv" variable is used somewhere in server.js, require('dotenv') alone cannot cause it. There could be problems with paths to .env that would be solved like https://stackoverflow.com/a/64734234/3731501 , but the error would be different
